# jQuery - Check if values of inputs, textareas and select not blank in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, if-statement

I have the following code which checks if the values of inputs, textareas and selects are blank, but rather than making functions for each I've tried to store them all into one variable using an array.

But, when the click handler is activated, something is causing the error message to appear even when all inputs on the page are filled in.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

HTML:

```
$('#saveInvoice').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $fields = [ $('input'), $('textarea'), $('select') ];
  var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value) === "";
  });
  if (!$emptyFields.length) {
    saveInvoice();
  } else {
    alert('Unable to save invoice. There are incomplete item fields.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following ...

```
$('#saveInvoice').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $fields = [ $('input'), $('textarea'), $('select') ];
  var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function(element) {
    return $.trim(element.val()) === "";
  });
  if (!$emptyFields.length) {
    saveInvoice();
  } else {
    alert('Unable to save invoice. There are incomplete item fields.');
  }
});
```

you should be getting the value of array elements

Comment: This kind of works, but is ignoring blank textareas for some reason

Comment: Not sure why. works fine for me tho.. do you have multiple textareas?

Comment: Yes, there are two on the page

Comment: Solved now. With you mentioning that I've edited the selectors to only fetch the value of the textarea in the main form, and then I've just added another function for the textarea on the page that is outside that form

Answer (score 1):

Replace this.value with **this.val()**

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

first : Jquery selectors. You've taken array of elements. $('input') gives you nodelist of all the inputs. you need to specify index of input you want to access value. for example $("input")[0] gives you first input found on your page.

second : You need to pass item to filter callback function. inside callback of filter this refer to window.

```js
$('#saveInvoice').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $fields = [ $('input')[0], $('textarea')[0], $('select')[0] ];
 
  var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function(ele) {
    console.log(ele.value);  
    return $.trim(ele.value) === "";
  });
  if (!$emptyFields.length) {
    //saveInvoice();
    
  } else {
    alert('Unable to save invoice. There are incomplete item fields.');
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

Input : <input type=""><br>

TextArea: <textarea></textarea><br>

Select: <select><option value="1">A</option></select>

<button id="saveInvoice">Save</button>

</form>
```